# Appended content do not get the proper CSS effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want append an HTML element into a `DIV`, but this one do not get the proper CSS like the original ones.

I have a dropdown menu, and want append on it new `<li>` rows.

**My HTML code:**

```
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="append">Append it</a>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5>Normal Dropdown Button</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <div id="append">

                   </div>
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>

   </div>


</div>
<br/><br/>
```

**My Javascript code:**

```
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.append', function( event ) {

      $("#append").append("<li><a href=\"#\">Item 1</a></li>");

      return false;

});
```

Here a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2136/

**EDITED WITH MY MAIN PROBLEM:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7gn020/1/

Click on APPEND IT, and then check the appended element by clicking on Select One button (Dropdown menu), and you will see that it do not get the proper CSS like the others (Item Test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've nested a `div` in the `ul` and the styles target `.dropdown-menu>li>a` so the div is breaking that. A `div` can't be a direct child of a `ul` and `li` can't be a direct child of a `div`. Instead of nesting a `div` in the `ul`, then appending `li`'s to the `div`, you can `$.prepend()` `li`'s directly to the menu, if you want them to appear at the beginning of the menu when you add them. If you don't care where they appear, you can `$.append()` them to the bottom instead.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.append', function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-menu").prepend("<li><a href=\"#\">Item Test</a></li>");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="append">Append it</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h5>Normal Dropdown Button</h5>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                     </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: @JisMaxi your fiddle doesn't do anything when I click "append it." But the root cause is still the same. Bootstrap's CSS targets `.dropdown-menu>li>a` which won't target the nested `ul` inside of `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `jquery` part.

```
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.append', function( event ) {

    $(".dropdown-menu").append("<li><a href=\"#\">Item 1</a></li>"); //append with ul, not div

    return false;

});
```

Comment: `#dropdown-menu` doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be `.dropdown-menu`

Answer (score 0):

The reason  behind the appended option having different css is due to the fact that you are appending it inside a div element.

The current CSS of the li elements comes from the bootstrap css with this selector.

```
   dropdown-menu>li>a
```

Since you have a div node inside ul (which is wrong and make html invalid) and you are appending a new li inside this div with JS, the above selector will not reach this node and CSS will not be applied.

You should add the li node directly under the ul node.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9med3Lou/